# Is the Karma bonus from a Karma boost not shown?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I recently started farming karma to get exotic armor pieces for my character and it takes a total of 252,000 karma to get a full set. As you know that is a lot so I bought some karma boosts in hopes of expediting this process.

I have done WvW for a while now so I know exactly how much karma each WvW event gives. When i used the Karma Boost, I did not see an increase in the karma from each event. Is the Karma boost actually working?

Comment: Since you've already got the karma boost, why not simply compare your total karma before and after the event?

Answer (score 3):

I also noticed this myself before. It does not show up on the amount you get from an event in the popup menu, however you do get the correct increase in your inventory karma amount.

More people verifying it [here](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/players/karma-boost)